# Map function returns array with undefined elements in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently has a component in which I have passed props into with the following `render` function:

```js
render(){
    return (
        <Card>
        <CardHeader>{this.props.title}</CardHeader>
        <CardBody>
            <CardSubtitle>Count: {Object.keys(this.props.machines).length}</CardSubtitle>
            {
                Object.keys(this.props.machines).length != 0 ? 
                <ListGroup>
                    {
                        console.log('array result: ',
                            Object.keys(this.props.machines).map((machine, key) => {
                                console.log('machine name: ', machine);
                                return
                                    <ListGroupItem key={key}>
                                        {machine}
                                    </ListGroupItem>
                            })
                        )
                    }
                    {
                        Object.keys(this.props.machines).map((machine, key) => {
                            console.log('machine name: ', machine);
                            return
                                <ListGroupItem key={key}>
                                    {machine}
                                </ListGroupItem>
                        })
                    }
                </ListGroup>
                
                         : null
            }
            
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
    );
}
```

The problem is that the array returned by the `map` function contains `undefined` elements as seen in the `console.log('array result: '...)`. However, the `console.log('machine name: ', machine)` does show individual string elements as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I have tried substituting `<ListGroupItem>` with other tags such as `div` but to no avail. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion). Beware of it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Wow! That is easy to overlook. Thank you for the heads up! Resolved the issue immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while returning from map, your JSX is in the next line to return so while compiling, automatic semicolon is inserted after return in which case it returns undefined, you must either have the JSX element in the same line or use `()`

```
{
     console.log('array result: ',
     Object.keys(this.props.machines).map((machine, key) => {
           console.log('machine name: ', machine);
           return (    // parenthesis here
                <ListGroupItem key={key}>
                    {machine}
                </ListGroupItem>
            )
     })
}
```

or

```
{
     console.log('array result: ',
     Object.keys(this.props.machines).map((machine, key) => {
           console.log('machine name: ', machine);
           return <ListGroupItem key={key}>
                    {machine}
                </ListGroupItem>
     })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Works now